# Calculate the percentage of success of each measurement values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 database tables with sample data given below

```
Meas_id - integer(Foreign keyed to Measurement.meas_id)    
Tool_id - integer(Foreign keyed to Events.Machine_id)    
Processdate- Timestamp with timezone (UTC)    
CreatedDate- Timestamp with timezone (UTC)
```

**Readings**

```
   Meas_id Tool_id    Status         Processdate
         1      13 Completed 2016-01-01 01:34:11
         1      28    Failed 2016-01-01 08:37:11
         1      54    Failed 2016-01-02 16:04:12
         1      32 Completed 2016-01-04 07:13:11
         1      39 Completed 2016-01-04 14:14:14
         1      12 Completed 2016-01-05 22:10:09
         1       9 Completed 2015-12-28 13:11:07
         1      17 Completed 2016-01-25 13:14:11
         1      27 Completed 2016-01-15 14:15:16
         1      31    Failed 2016-01-07 16:08:04
         2     113 Completed 2016-01-01 01:34:11
         2     128    Failed 2016-01-01 08:37:11
         2     154    Failed 2016-01-02 16:04:12
         2     132 Completed 2016-01-04 07:13:11
         2     139 Completed 2016-01-04 14:14:14
         2     112 Completed 2016-01-05 22:10:09
         2      90 Completed 2015-12-28 13:11:07
         2     117 Completed 2016-01-25 13:14:11
         2     127 Completed 2016-01-15 14:15:16
         2     131    Failed 2016-01-07 16:08:04
```

**Events**

```
   Meas_id Machine_id Event_Name         CreatedDate
         1         13    Success 2015-12-27 01:34:11
         1         17      Error 2015-12-27 08:37:11
         1         28    Success 2015-12-27 16:04:12
         1          9    Success 2015-12-28 07:13:11
         1         54    Success 2015-12-28 14:14:14
         1         31      Error 2015-12-28 22:10:09
         1         32    Success 2015-12-29 13:11:07
         1         39    Success 2015-12-29 13:14:11
         1         12    Success 2015-12-31 14:15:16
         1         27    Success 2016-01-01 16:08:04
         2        113    Success 2015-12-27 01:34:11
         2        117      Error 2015-12-27 08:37:11
         2        128    Success 2015-12-27 16:04:12
         2         90    Success 2015-12-28 07:13:11
         2        154    Success 2015-12-28 14:14:14
         2        131      Error 2015-12-28 22:10:09
         2        132    Success 2015-12-29 13:11:07
         2        139    Success 2015-12-29 13:14:11
         2        112    Success 2015-12-31 14:15:16
         2        127    Success 2016-01-01 16:08:04
```

**Mesurement**

```
  Meas_id Meas_name
        1    Length
        2   Breadth
```

For each measurement ‘length’ and ‘breadth’ and each day of the week, I am trying to calculate the percentage of success in the first week of 2016 for all completed measurements of tools/machines within 168 hours of thier creation date.

**My Desired Output is**

```
   Measurement DayofTheWeek PercentageSuccess
        Length            1                50
        Length            2                 0
        Length            3                 0
        Length            4               100
        Length            5               100
        Length            6                 0
        Length            7                 0
       Breadth            1                50
       Breadth            2                 0
       Breadth            3                 0
       Breadth            4               100
       Breadth            5               100
       Breadth            6                 0
       Breadth            7                 0
```

I tried doing it this way but certainly missing some logic and its not working.

```
Select m.Meas_name, 
datepart(dd, Processdate) as DayofTheWeek,
(Count(m.Meas_name)* 100 / (Select Count(Event_Name) From Events where Event_Name = 'Success')) as PercentageSuccess

FROM Readings r JOIN
Measurements m
ON r.Meas_id = m.Meas_id
JOIN Events e
ON e.Meas_id = m.Meas_id
WHERE m.Meas_name IN ('Length', 'Breadth') AND
r.Status = 'Completed' AND
e.CreatedDate >= DATEADD(hh, -168, GETDATE())
GROUP BY m.Meas_name, datepart(dd, Processdate);
```

Kindly provide inputs on an optimized way of achieving it.

Comment: I've removed postgresql and tsql tags. Please tag your question with appropriate DBMS you are using.

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? Do you get an error? If so what is it? Or is the data not as you expected, in that case, what are you getting and what are you expecting to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice I got downvoted for a correct answer probably because my answer wasn't very clear it is kind of hard to explain so here is an edit aimed at your comment and the downvoter (whom I think was just retaliating).

Anyway, Your joining of 3 tables while valid replicates the data in your events table.  Due to that the way you are counting the records will always be exaggerated and incorrect.  your calculation for percentage is also happens to be backwards.

On the join it looks like you are just missing the use of the Tool_id in your join.  You could try something like the following:

```
SELECT
    m.Meas_name
    ,DAYOFWEEK(r.ProcessDate) as DayOfTheWeek
    ,(COUNT(CASE WHEN e.Event_Name = 'Success' tHEN e.Meas_id END)/(COUNT(e.Meas_id) * 1.0)) * 100 as PercentageSuccess
FROM
    Measurements m
    INNER JOIN Events e
    ON m.Meas_id = e.Meas_id
    INNER JOIN Readings r
    ON e.Meas_id = r.Meas_id
    AND e.Machine_id = r.Tool_id
    AND r.Status = 'Completed'
    AND r.ProcessDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-07'
WHERE
    m.Meas_name IN ('Length','Breadth')
GROUP BY
    m.Meas_name
    ,DAYOFWEEK(r.ProcessDate)
```

Note this is written for mysql because that is what is tagged in you post.  if you actually want sql-server as your syntax suggests let me know.  Also, I am guessing that you a really want to filter by processdate but if you want to filter by Event.CreateDate then put that in the ON condition of the Events join.

Comment: I get your point here but I wanted to check when a succesfull event is created in the events table, how many were completed and how many failed and then wanted to calculate the percentage of success. This is just a sample fake data that I provided here. I can modify it but I would like to know why we would want to use day of week from events? the question is to get the data for the first week of 2016. I am learning SQL and haven't come across conditional aggregation but will look into it.

Comment: it looks like your missing link is the Tool_Id on Readings to Machine_id on Events which will create a relationship between the 2 tables so taht you can effectively join, filter and count.  I will update the answer

Comment: answer updated. If you more clearly define what date you are trying to filter such as when readings occur or when events occur I can change this around a little easier

Comment: Thanks Matt. Makes a lot of sense now with this explanation. I am not sure why you were downvoted earlier cos I felt you gave an idea of what has to be done. Anyway, I will try your solution in my bigger dataset to see how it handles various conditions and also NULLS if any in columns. I am good with mysql and I can convert it back to sql-server if needed. Do you think we need any special care towards NULLS? Was just curious since I am starting to learn SQL and want to get better at it.

Comment: Aggregate functions COUNT(), SUM(), etc. will ignore nulls so as long as you are counting a column with a null and you want them to be ignored then you should be file if you want them counted then you would have to deal with the null value.  If you are filtering on a column that has nulls e.g. Success then those will be dropped off too but that is probably what you desire as well.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I will note this when I am working with a lot of NULLS.